# How can I create a standard site template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: site-template

I want to create a standard site template which I can choose if I want create a new subsite.

Can you show me the steps to make this possible=

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to save the current site as a site template?

**1)** select the settings icon (top right)

**2)** click site settings

**3)** under site actions click on "Save Site as Template"

**4)** fill in all the feilds (site name, template name) , check include content and click ok

**5)** template is now saved within the solution gallery, you can create a subsite using this template

hope it helps :)

Comment: i do not see "Save Site as Template" at root. Tried the workaround "_layouts/savetmpl.aspx" , getting error

Comment: what is the error your getting?

Comment: I don't see this link too on Public Site

Comment: in order to "save site as template", your site has to have publishing turned on.  If you used the Development site template when creating your site, publishing will be turned off by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check This Video Link it Shows how to Create Site Template in SharePoint 2013.
http://www.fpweb.net/support/microsoft-sharepoint/tutorials/sharepoint-2013/customization/create-site-template/